# Python3 Print Tuple in another class

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have this code which splits a tuple which is fetched from an SQL record. I can get this to print off into the module but need it to print into an entry box in another class. This is the current code, I have tried to include only the relevant components::

```
class Accounts(object):
    def __init__(self, window):

    def View_Account(self, index):
        global Account
        Account = (self.cur.fetchone())
        (Name, DOB, Address) = tuple(Account)
```

Then in another class I have created an entrybox for each variable, for example the Name:

```
class Edit(Accounts):
    def __init__(self, window):

    self.ent_Name = Entry(self.FrameEdit, font =("Arial","16"),  width = 20)
    self.ent_Name.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
```

I was wondering how the Name in the tuple could be printed off into the entry box, I tried text =, but it came up with an error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried `self.ent_Name.insert(0, <Name or some value>)`?

Comment: Hi, I tried that but it came up with the error:      `TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`

Comment: the second argument has to be the name value you wish to insert

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure we are on the same page. The Name is fetched from the database and so the value changes when a different account is clicked on.